# VBA - out of memory error when copying and pasting data

Tags: excel, vba

In a worksheet, I have a large number of formulas/data/cells. I want to paste them as values and then save/close the file. I have the following code:

```
With Workbooks("Sample Workbook").Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
Workbooks("Sample Workbook").Save
Application.Quit
```

However, the code gives the out of memory error at `.Value = .Value` line. How do I fix it?

Comment: ① Is this the only code in this procedure (Sub)? ② Are there any events in Sheet1? If so try to disable events before `.Value = .Value` and enable them afterwards with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and in the end `… = True`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It is not the only code in the procedure.. there are other stuff too. I will try `Application.EnableEvents` Thanks